# Laravel Echo + Socket.io, Access from other devices?

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm currently working on a video chat project with Laravel Echo as the base, with Socket.io-client  as the base. Currently, it works in the browser via WebRTC without any issues, especially with Echo's channels.

The issue is with accessing the Socket.io link from Laravel Echo. When accessing the direct link (`https://<server ip>:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`), the connection gives out a a 0 message with the connection's SID and pings and a 40 message. When you wait too long, or when you send a mesaage on the Echo tester, it disconnects instantly.

Is this due to not providing any form of authentication when connecting? I'm only assuming this because of Laravel Echo's requirement of a Bearer token and a XSRF-Token when connecting. Do I need to modify my code to send those headers as well?